# Going from (p ∧ ~q) ∨ (~p ∧ q) to (p ∨ q) ∧ (~p ∨~q)

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I am confused on how to go from (p ∧ ~q) ∨ (~p ∧ q) to (p ∨ q) ∧ (~p ∨ ~q). I know they are equal because I plugged them into a truth table and all of the rows have the same values. What would be some of the rules I could use to prove these two to be logically equivalent? I think I would need to use DeMorgan's Law at some point but I think there may be a step before that.

Comment: HINT: It will be a couple application of DeMorgan's Laws. Notice that you have "A or B" as a general form, which is equivalent to the negation of a conjunction Not A' and B'.

Answer (score 4):

You can just expand everything out:
\begin{align*}
(p \land \neg q) \lor (\neg p \land q)
&\equiv (p \lor \neg p) \land (p \lor q) \land (\neg q \lor \neg p) \land (\neg q \lor q) &\text{by Distributivity Law}\\
&\equiv (p \lor \neg p) \land (p \lor q) \land (\neg p \lor \neg q) \land (q \lor \neg q) &\text{by Commutativity Law}\\
&\equiv (\top) \land (p \lor q) \land (\neg p \lor \neg q) \land (\top) &\text{by Inverse Law}\\
&\equiv (p \lor q) \land (\neg p \lor \neg q) &\text{by Identity Law}\\
\end{align*}